# Get size of image on a web page

Tags: c#, .net, image, http, http-headers

Is it possible to retrieve information about images on a web site without having to atually download the actual image?  I am interested in width/height and kb size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can get the file size using the `Content-Length` header but you would need to at least start downloading the image to get the width/height.

Once the image starts downloading you could parse the stream and as @BrokenGlass and @Ed Swangren suggest try to find the image width/height that way.

Having said that, it sounds like an awful lot of work given that you can quickly find the image width/height using available libraries if you download the entire image. Unless you're dealing with massive images or a massive number of images it may just be easier to download the files and check their size that way.

Comment: I agree that the OP may not actually need to parse the header, but I figure this question will serve others who actually do have this specific performance constraint.  As far as the OP goes we have no way to know.

Comment: Very true, but I would just like to place a warning marker along their path letting them know that reading the headers out of streaming images is a huge amount of effort for a (probably) very small reward.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't actually know if the image will be large or small, so in some cases it may be a performance issue if the image is large.  I will look into image format specifications to see if I can mitigate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Some image formats contain size information in the header.  You could parse the header to figure out the size, but of course the implementation will vary depending upon the image format.

Comment: Since the original question is tagged with the `http-headers` tag, I believe that you rather mean the header of the image, i.e. the first bytes of the binary representation of the image. Right?

Comment: Yes, I do mean the image header.

Answer (score 1):

The file size of the image you could determine with an HTTP HEAD request, the response will contain the content-length, in the case of .NET that would be `HttpResponse.ContentLength`.

For determining the width/height of many image formats you only need some bytes at the beginning of the file, so you could start with that - as mentioned it depends on the actual image format though.

Comment: Good answer, although there's no guarantee that HEAD will actually be supported.